# Changing permalink structure for Posts

Tags: permalinks

I'm just a beginner with wordpress and I wanted to know, if I can change the permalink structure for my posts (I already have about 10 or more Posts) from

**http://www.example.com/example-post/ => http://www.example.com/%category%/%postname%/** without losing the redirects to my 'old' posts. Thank you in advance, really appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "without losing the redirects to my 'old' posts". Can you elaborate? Do you need redirects from the old post to the new URL structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your permalink structure from settings->permalinks option in wp-admin.

Please check below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I thought changing the permalink structure causes a lot of errors and broken links. But I tried it (thanks for the screenshot) and everything is working. Maybe Wordpress automatically creates the redirects.